# Server side pagination with limited number of requests

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5, feathersjs

My front-end is Angular5. Back-end is REST API NODE.JS and the database is POSTGRES.

Table named organization in my postgres contain 100k ( 100 000) rows.

I have table that contains list of all organizations with information such as name of the organization,location etc.

At this moment my frontend only displays 50 organization.  I have console logged this and my backend is only sending array of 50.

**My goal is to display all organizations( 100 000 of them) in the frontend table using server-side pagination.**

Pagination is already made for the current values that are displayed and thats 50 of them. Code is below

Frontend table below that works ( currently displaying only 50 organization sent from backend)

```
 <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">

            <div class="table-col">
                <div class="card table">
                    <div class="row header">
                        <div class="col col-md-6">Name</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">ID</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">Location</div>
                        <div class="col col-md-2">Person in charge</div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngFor="let group of organizations">
                        <div *ngIf="group.name == 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let organization of group.array |  search: term | orderBy: order | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 13, currentPage:page1, id: '1'}"
                                [routerLink]="['/organization/edit', organization.id]">
                                <div class="col col-md-6">{{organization.name}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.id}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2"  *ngIf="organization.place?.fullName != null">{{organization.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                <div class="col col-md-2"  *ngIf="organization.place?.fullName == null"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div>
                                <div *ngIf="organization.person?.fullname != null" class="col col-md-2">{{organization.person?.fullname}}

                                </div>
                                 <div *ngIf="organization.person?.fullname == null" class="col col-md-2"><span class="badge badge-danger">-- N/A -- </span></div> 


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="group.name != 'all'">
                            <div class="row content-row">
                                <div class="col col-md-12 group-name" (click)="toggleGroup(group.name)">{{group.name + ':'}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="showGroup == group.name">
                                <div class="row content-row" *ngFor="let organization of group.array | search: term |   paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage:page2, id: '2'}"
                                    [routerLink]="['/organization/edit', organization.id]">
                                    <div class="col col-md-6" style="padding-left:23px;">{{organization.name}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.id}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.place?.fullName}}</div>
                                    <div class="col col-md-2">{{organization.person?.fullname}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!(organizations[0].array.length > 0)" class="row noResults">
                        <label>No results..</label>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="organizations[0].name == 'all'" class="paggination-row">
                        <div class="paggination">
                            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page1 = $event" id="1" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                                nextLabel="Next">
                            </pagination-controls>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="organizations[0].name != 'all' && showGroup != ''" class="paggination-row">
                        <div class="paggination">
                            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page2 = $event" id="2" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" autoHide="true" previousLabel="Previous"
                                nextLabel="Next">
                            </pagination-controls>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now on backend in my config I have the following code:

```
   "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 3030,
      "public": "../public/",
      "paginate": {
          "default": 50,
        "max": 50
      },
```

Note: host ip changed on purpose.
Paginate is the reason why my front is only receiving 50 values when there is 100 000 of them.

Now if I go on about and change default and max value to 100k my frontend should show all organizations but will probably crash the client and the server in process of doing this.

If i do paginate false that won't be much of a help either.

**Now I am wondering how can I keep having limited requests like 50 or 100(so my server is alive) but still show all organizations in my front-end using server side pagination or whatever necessary.**

Any help is appreciated and thank you so much for taking your time to read this.

edit1: service to load all organizations:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppSettings } from '../../../../../../app.settings';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

//service made to comunicate with backend
@Injectable()
export class CreateOrganizacijeService {
    private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>("default")
    currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    updateData(data) {
        this.dataSource.next(data);
    }

    getAll() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/organization', { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    getOne(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/organization?id=' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    createNew(organization) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/organization', organization, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    delete(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.delete(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/organization?id=' + id, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }

    edit(id, organization) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let token = localStorage.getItem('feathers-jwt');

        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
        return this.http.patch(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/organization?id=' + id, organization, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

component ngonit ( where I load organizations)

```
  ngOnInit() {

     this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if(this.currentUser.roleId == '2') {
      this.isAdmin = true; //check if user is admin
  }
        if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).roleId == '2') {
            this.isAdmin = true; //check if user is admin
        }
        this.organizacijeService.currentData.subscribe(res => {

                this.loadOrgs();

        })



    }

    loadOrgs() {
        this.organizacijeService.getAll().subscribe(res => {
            this.organizations[0].array = res.data;
            console.log(this.organizations[0])
        }, err => {
            this.toast.error('Organization: ' + JSON.parse(err._body).message, 'Failed')
        })
    }
```

Comment: If I manually go to my localhost:3000/organization and write localhost:3000/organization?$limit=20&$skip=20 I can show other blocks of data, so they exist they are there on the API. Now how do I edit my pagination and my service to retrieve other blocks as well and paginate them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load subsequent pages by increasing the [$skip query parameter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html#skip) in increments of 50 until the `page.total - 50`.

I would keep in mind that showing 100k records at once will probably still lead to performance problems on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Will I be writing skip paramater in different getall2 function with forloop to have increments of 50 on click of page/button and then somehow append both resoults in one array or? Thanks again

Comment: It will only return the data from the request. You'd have to maintain and append to a global array yourself.

Comment: What I did was upon page load to send request with query set with limit 50, and skip 0.

Changed pagination to execute query adding +50 skip on every page, and used totalitems on pagination to calculate res.total. Everything works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proxy service on the server side that has pagination disabled:

```
app.use('organizations-unpaginated', {
  find(params){
    const _params = Object.assign({}, params, { paginate: false });
    return app.service('organizations').find(_params);
  }
})
```

As Daff said, you will run into performance issues and I'd generally say that rendering 100k DOM elements (almost all of which are invisible anyway) is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to read and share your ideas! I was able to make it work.